# c++ string literal as template parameter

Tags: c++

ive been thinking about this for a long time but I still have no idea of what T would be in case follow.

```
template <typename T>
void print(const T& a) {
  std::cout << a;
}
int main()
{
print("hello");
}
```

I know

```
void print(const char* const& a)
{
  std::cout << a << "here";
}
```

would work so I am assuming T would be char* const.  I just wanna be crystal clear.

what would T be?

Comment: `char[6] const&`

Comment: `In instantiation of 'void print(const T&) [with T = char [6]]'` - force a compiler error - live - https://godbolt.org/z/GM388EWGb

Comment: Or like this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bTqf3d3MY

Comment: @CodyGray That's not a valid type, you probably meant `const char (&)[6]`. But `T` deduces to `char[6]` here.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I used a utility function to print out the type of `a`, then I just pasted the output literally while I went looking for a duplicate that StoryTeller found before I could. I thought it would be obvious enough that the type of `T` is `const char[6]` (yes, the `const` is still there; it's a string literal after all!).

Comment: but void print(const char[6]& a) won't work. (I just simply sub T with char[6])

Comment: However, void print(const char(&a)[6]) this is working.